# ggplot emulating type="b". Joining the dots

Tags: r, ggplot2

Questions asking how to plot with points joined by lines as in the basic graphics `plot(x,y, type="b")` are quite frequent here. Alas, I have not been able to apply the answers to my case (nor frequently even to understand them). So I must ask again.

I have the following code:

```
DateLabels <- c("9/13", "10/13", "11/13", "12/13", "1/14", "2/14", "3/14", "4/14", "5/14", "6/14", "7/14", "8/14")
ABC1 <-c(27,NA,NA,NA,32, 36, 39, 35, 32,NA,NA,NA) # blue
C2DE <-c(36,NA,NA,NA,41, 38, 39, 42, 32,NA,NA,NA) # red
votingIntention <- data.frame(Dates=DateLabels, ABC1=ABC1, C2DE=C2DE)

ggplot(votingIntention) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=DateLabels) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(25,50)) +
  geom_point(aes(x=DateLabels, y=ABC1), colour="blue") +
  geom_point(aes(x=DateLabels, y=C2DE), colour="red")
```

I want to modify the code so that the red dots are joined by line segments just as in basic graphics. Note that in the dates there is a gap from 9/13 to 1/14.

This should be very simple, and probably is when you know how!

Comment: I would recommend adding `+ geom_line(aes(x=DateLabels, y=C2DE, group = 1), colour="red")` but it doesn't draw the last line for some reason

Comment: NA is the reason, I believe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing some data reshaping prior to plotting. I wasn't sure how to do all that in `ggplot` so here's the code

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

#melt data, order factors, remove missing values    
mm<-melt(votingIntention, id.vars="Dates")
mm$Dates<-factor(mm$Dates, levels=DateLabels)
mm<-mm[complete.cases(mm),]

#plot lines and points
ggplot(mm, aes(x=Dates, y=value, colour=variable, group=variable)) +
    scale_x_discrete(limits=DateLabels) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits=c(25,50)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line() +
    scale_colour_manual(values=c("blue","red"))
```

[image: sample output]

Like I said, I reshaped it so all the `y` values were in the same column and colored the points/lines based on the `variable` variable returned from `melt`. Also, `qqplot` doesn't seem to like plotting lines across categorical `x` values so I converted the Dates to numeric values in the `geom_line` call. To make this work, I had to make sure the `Dates` factor in the data had it's levels in calendar order rather than alphabetical as is the default.

Comment: you can use the `group` aesthetic rather than converting dates to numeric (by default, ggplot separates the data into groups by factor levels): I would suggest `ggplot(mm,aes(x=Dates,y=value,colour=variable,group=variable)) + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(25,50)) +  geom_point()+geom_line()+  scale_colour_manual(values=c("blue","red"))`. (It's too bad there's not a `geom_pointline()` analogous to `geom_pointrange()`.)

Comment: Thanks @BenBolker. It seems your method w/o the scale_x_ discrete drops the missing dates, but i'll make those other changes.

Comment: Thanks! Many things I did not understand made clear by your code. Hopefully will help other people too.